# Weighted graph drawing using Sage

Tags: graph, nodes, sage, weighted, vertices

I was trying to draw a weight graph using Sage for a 10x10 matrix, A. I used the following code:

```
G = DiGraph(A, format='weighted_adjacency_matrix')

H = G.plot(edge_labels=False, graph_border=True)

H.show()
```

I was wondering if someone could help me change the starting node from 0 to 1. Currently the node labes are 0,1,...9 but I would prefer them to be 1,...,10.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It took me a lot longer to find this than it should have.

```
G.relabel([1..10],inplace=True)
```

This function actually has quite a few nice features.

Comment: Is there also a way to highlight a specific route through this graph?